# mysql_query() - PROTOCOL

Tags: mysql, c, tcp

If I am not mistaken, mysql_query() function sends data using the TCP protocol.
Is it possible to reassemble the query tcp packets , which - say are send over the network -  and reconstruct the query at some other place?

I hope the below image will explain my question more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. All you need is a monitoring sowtware (like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)), computer2 (where you have that software installed) must know the I.P of the source or the destination mysql server and also be able to intercept those packets. (F.instance being in the same wireless connection -or location and monitoring- of the source or destination).

After that, you've got the packets but in order to read them it depends of the settings of the connection between the client and the server. Mysql can establish some kind of compression, in that case you should decompress the packets. Also it could happen that client/server connection follow a SSL protocol, in which case you should decrypt the packets... etc.

Not easy at all, but possible.